# REGEX PCRE - Avoid string and the first instance of any string within a parenthesis

Tags: regex, pcre

Here is an example of the sort of strings I am working with:

> [TEXT1] TEXT EXAMPLE HERE (ROBERT_01) MORE TEXT HERE POSSIBLY SOME NUMBERS 9999 THEN TEXT (JIMBO_01)

What I am trying to do is remove everything AFTER the first set of brackets i.e. "(ROBERT_01)".

I can get it to work whilst explicitly stating the text itself e.g.:

```
(?<=TEXT EXAMPLE HERE \(ROBERT_01\)).+
```

However this is problematic as the string between the parenthesis isn't always "ROBERT_01".

EDIT: Note, I am using the FME transformer 'StringReplacer' which utilises Regex.

Comment: You don't need a lookbehind. You need a capturing group or `\K` token: `\(ROBERT_\d+\)\K.*`. Live demo https://regex101.com/r/nujsAG/1

Comment: the revo's solution is good; if could be really anything inside parentheses, use `^.*?\(.*?\)\K.*` , instead: https://regex101.com/r/sYTr8l/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you might do is match not an opening parenthesis one or more times until you encounter an opening parenthesis using a negated [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[^(]+`. Then match the opening parenthesis `\(`, match not a closing parentheses zero or more times `[^)]*` and then match the closing parenthesis `\)`.

That will match `[TEXT1] TEXT EXAMPLE HERE (ROBERT_01)`

Then use `\K` so previously consumed characters are no longer included in the final match.

Finally match any character zero or more times `.*` and would match:

`MORE TEXT HERE POSSIBLY SOME NUMBERS 9999 THEN TEXT (JIMBO_01)`

**Regex**

[`[^(]+\([^)]*\)\K.*`](https://regex101.com/r/9O0ZbS/1)

Answer (score 0):

Regular expression can be

```
/\(.*?\)(.*?)$/gm
```

This will capture the text between parentheses on first match and the remaining text on the second,

See it at [online regex tester](https://regex101.com/r/NW6aLd/2)

But maybe you need this other which just matches text from the beginning of string to the first text enclosed by parentheses

```
/^(.*?)\s?\(.*\).*$/
```

See it also at [online regex tester](https://regex101.com/r/dPkEcx/1)

Comment: Thanks for the response! Both codes for me ("\(.*?\)(.*?)$") and ("\(.*?\)(.*?)$") grabs (and thus will remove) everything past the "TEXT EXAMPLE" phase including the first set of parenthesis.